# How to let Visio shapesheet SETF() get the cell formula instead of the value?

Tags: visio

I want to change an arrow's direction in a Visio chart. I wrote an action for the arrow shape:

=SETF(GetRef(User.Temp),BeginArrow)+SETF(GetRef(BeginArrow),EndArrow)+SETF(GetRef(EndArrow),User.Temp)

But when the arrow end is a formula, e.g., =USE("Composite"), the SETF() function can only get the value "0" instead of the formula. How can I keep the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried but could not find a way to copy the formula from one ShapeSheet cell to another using VISIO function.
For this specific action (swap line ends), I can use the VISIO provided command: Shape -> Operations -> Reverse Ends.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try syntax like

```
SETF(GetRef(User.Temp),"BeginArrow")
```

Read more about [SETF Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/setf-function)
**Update** when you write formula with [function USE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/use-function) you must wrap in double commas name of line end

```
SETF(GetRef(BeginArrow),"Use(""f"")")+SETF(GetRef(EndArrow),"Use(""f"")")
```

Comment: Thank you. But I did not get expected value by this.  Assume `BeginArrow` contains formula `Use("Composite")`. The syntax `SETF(GetRef(User.Temp), "BeginArrow")` will assign `BeginArrow` cell reference instead of the formula. The syntax `SETF(GetRef(User.Temp), BeginArrow)` will assign the evaluated formula result `0` to `User.Temp`. But I expects `Use("Composite")` to be assigned to `User.Temp`.

Comment: I made goog experience by adding an "=" sign in front of the formula. SETF(GetRef(BeginArrow),"=Use(""f"")")